# TFS Build failed due to InstallShield Exception

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-definition, installshield-2013

We are using **InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition** with TFS 2013 Build Server.
Occasionally our tfs XAML builds failed with error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets (108): Exception Caught

License of InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition is successfully activated on Build Server Machine(WIN 7 machine).
Due to this error, complete build failed. To fix this, we need to restart tfs build server machine.
Please suggestion some permanent fix for this issue. Let me know if need any additional information.

Comment: What's the exception that's caught?

Comment: @DanielMann Not sure about the exception. Check following screenshotswhich showing the error I am getting during build failure. Also, check corresponding information at Build Explorer app: http://imgur.com/a/04rmE and http://imgur.com/a/gbpyq

Comment: "To fix this, we need to restart tfs build server machine.", do you mean the issue does not occur after restart the build server?

Comment: Yes, just after the tfs build server restart, the error doesn't appears immediately. However, it should occur in future build sporadically.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you get error saying InstallShield.Tasks.dll was not found or could not be loaded like screenshot below:

[image]

> Solution:
>
> Set the MSBuild Platform on your Build Definition to “X86” as shown
>   below:

[image]

2. If you get error saying InstallShield Licence has expired like screenshot below:

[image]

> Solution:
>
> Set your Build Service to run with a domain account instead of
>   “NT_AUTHORITY\Network Service”.

Comment: I am already having have both the settings on the build definition and build-server machine.
Check following screenshots which shows the error I am getting during build failure. Also, check corresponding information at Build Explorer app.
[link]<img src="http://imgur.com/a/04rmE">[link]
[link]<img src="http://imgur.com/a/gbpyq">[link]
Not sure how to get exact error/exception corresponding to this. Please confirm.

Comment: Another significant point is, at the time of build failure due to installshield error, following error appears at event viewer:
Upgrade Error: Windows Agent upgrade request on hold while awaiting shutdown of MSIExec. This may require manual intervention to correct.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. But according to your log file, you are using 2013Limited, which is not the latest version. Please get the latest version from website http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio?lang=1033&ver=ult and have another try. (I tested with the latest version of InstallShield and with TFS 2013.5+VS 2013.5).